# numpy argsort yields TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python-3.6

```
import numpy as np
a = [3.1,5.1,34.2,1.5,2.4,6.4]
b = [234,5,5,465,873,345]
idx = np.argsort(a)
a = a[idx]
b = b[idx]
```

I am using Python 3.6.

From numpy argsort I get an array of integers and with this I want to rearrange my arrays, but instead I get the error:

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

a and b must be numpy arrays to be sorted like this.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([3.1,5.1,34.2,1.5,2.4,6.4])
b = np.array([234,5,5,465,873,345])
idx = np.argsort(a)
a = a[idx]
b = b[idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np

a = [3.1,5.1,34.2,1.5,2.4,6.4]
b = [234,5,5,465,873,345]
inds = np.argsort(a)
a = [a[idx] for idx in inds]
b = [b[idx] for idx in inds]
```

You can also do this.

Answer (score -2):

What is your question exactly? Do you want to just sort your arrays?

If so then it should be simply:

```
a = [3.1,5.1,34.2,1.5,2.4,6.4]
b = [234,5,5,465,873,345]
a = np.argsort(a)
b = np.argsort(b)
```

If the question is something else then please let me know.

Comment: I thought with np.argsort(a) I would get the list of indices corresponding to the sorted order of list a, then I want to rearrange lists a and b according to the rearrangement of list a. I expected to get this: a[idx] = [1.5, 2.4, 3.1, 5.1, 6.4, 34.2] and b[idx] = [465, 873, 234, 5, 345, 5]

Comment: np.argsort returns indices which would sort the array - [link to documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)